# Adding a 1 pixel height view to Linear Layout causes Buttons to stop working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have extended a LinearLayout, and I am using the following code to make a grid like structure of buttons in it

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);

    for(int currentRow=1; currentRow<=5; ++currentRow) {
        LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1);
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        if (currentRow!=1) {
            View horizontalLine = new View(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalLineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            horizontalLine.setLayoutParams(horizontalLineParams);
            horizontalLine.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
            horizontalLayout.addView(horizontalLine);
        }

        for(int currentColumn=1; currentColumn<=3; ++currentColumn) {
            Button button = new Button(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
            button.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
            button.setId(currentColumn + (currentRow - 1) * mPatternSize.numberOfColumns);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            horizontalLayout.addView(button);

            if (currentColumn!=mPatternSize.numberOfColumns) {
                View verticalLine = new View(mContext);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams verticalLineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                verticalLine.setLayoutParams(verticalLineParams);
                verticalLine.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(0xff000000));
                horizontalLayout.addView(verticalLine);
            }
        }

        this.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }
```

In this scenario, the first 'if' block is the offending block, whenever it is true, it causes the buttons to disappear, but the seperators still work. What should I do?

In my activity, this LinearLayout is defined as

```
<me.rijul.knockcode.KnockCodeButtonView
    android:id="@+id/knockCodeView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

I have been trying to fix this for the past 4 hours, but I have gotten nowhere. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: You say you are adding a 1px height, but I see you are adding a 120pixel margin?

Comment: Sorry, that was just me attempting to debug it anyway. Removed that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons disappear because you insert into a horizontal LinearLayout a view with width=MATCH_PARENT, so it occupies the whole width of the layout:

```
  ...
  horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  if (currentRow!=1) {
        View horizontalLine = new View(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalLineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
  ...
```

Comment: But the buttons are a child of this horizontal layout, are they not?

Comment: Okay, I got it. The horizontal line should be added toe the parent linear layout using `this.addView(horizontalLine);`